# After switching from Windows to Linux i can't open the site i'm working on

Tags: php, linux, twig

I keep getting a http 500 error when trying to open my website from the browser. Apache is running, I'm absolutely sure. So far I've determined that there is a difference between "\" and "/" in Linux and Windows.

This is my home controller

```
use Yee/Yee;
use Yee/Managers/RoutingCacheManager;
use Yee/Managers/CacheManager;

class HomeController extends \Yee\Managers\Controller\Controller
{


    /**
     * @Route('/')
     * @Name('home.index')
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $app = $this->getYee();
        $app->render('home DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR home.twig', $data = array(

        ));
    }


}
```

This is the TWIG page i want to render

```
<div>
<h1> Welcome to my YeePHP project</h1>
<h1> Click <a href=" register "> here </a> to register</h1>
<h1> Click <a href=" login "> here </a> to login</h1>
<h1> Click <a href=" dashboard "> here </a> to enter the dashboard</h1>
```

Currently working on Ubuntu 16.04. Everything worked fine on Windows 10.

Comment: `use Yee\Yee;` instead of `use Yee/Yee;` --- check slash

Comment: Doesn't work, sadly. I've been trying all variations for about half a day.

Comment: Because in the provided code i only see something wrong is the slash. Are you changing every where or just Yee\Yee. change every slash.

Comment: Everywhere, not just in the use's but in the routes.

Comment: no not in routes only with use and class  in url a/b is same in windows and linux

Comment: `$app->render('home'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'home.twig', $data);`

Comment: DarkBee, you have done the impossible. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

DarkBee got it figured out.

`$app->render('home'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'home.twig', $data);` does the trick.